How can I divide two ranges which on two different spreadsheets using variables to feed the Row number with VBScript?
How can I divide two ranges which on two different spreadsheets using variables to feed the Row number with VBScript?
I tried following code:
Sheet1.Range("A10:M10") = Sheet1.Evaluate("Sheet1!A9:M9/Sheet2!A3:M3")

The above statement and it's works just fine and I get correct calculation on Sheet1 (in range A10-M10).
But I can’t find out how to use Variable in Evaluate method, I tied following…
Set LnTot = 9
set LnPer = 10
Sheet1.Range("A" & LnPer, "M" & LnPer) = Sheet1.Evaluate("Sheet1!A &LnTot, M &LnTot/Sheet2!A3:M3")

